# access UILabel using tag notation

Tags: ios, objective-c, tags, uilabel

I have created several UILabels each with their own .tag value. I am then trying to populate the UILabel with a NSString from another class which calls a method from the calls that has set the UILabels using the .tag

however when I try to access the label in my debug section its showing the label as null and the text is never set.

this is what my method looks like thats being called from the other calss.

```
- (void) SymbolButtonPressed:(NSString *)selectedString {

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cutField viewWithTag:currentlySelectedTag];
    [label setText:selectedString];

}
```

label = null when I am debugging this code... I am not sure why

as requested this is how I add the label

```
axesView = [[UIView alloc] init];
axesView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, scrollWidth+10, 77.0);


cutField = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i*40)+2, 35, 40, 40)];
cutField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[cutField setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
cutField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20];
cutField.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
cutField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:colorController.grRed/255.0 green:colorController.grGreen/255.0 blue:colorController.grBlue/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor];
cutField.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
[axView addSubview:cutField];
```

Comment: Is the label, you are searching for, a subview of cutField?

Comment: Have you tried (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:currentlySelectedTag];? Maybe you are adding the mentioned UILabel to self.view. Can you post the code where you add the label?

Comment: What is cutField? If the view you're trying to access by tag is in a different controller from the one where you have the SymbolButtonPressed: method, then you need to get a reference to that other controller before you can access any of its views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others have hinted at, you almost always want to use your view controller's content view in calls to viewWithTag. That method will walk all the subviews, sub-views, and sub-subviews until it finds your tag. By using self.view, it works no matter where the tagged view is in your view hierarchy, and works even if you move the view into a different subview later (which happens more often than you think.)